# ssh to cisco ASA and store output to a file

Tags: ssh, expect, cisco

I am having trouble writing a shell-script for ssh into cisco ASA and store command output in a text file.

1.key exchange not needed in the script as it is not first time log in.
2. from my centOS server it should log into cisco ASA with ssh usr@serverip, run "en", send en password
and then run some command say "show version" and store the output to a text file in my server. I tried both shell script and the use of expect, not successful in either. Please help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: [RANCID](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/) (Really Awesome New Cisco confIg Differ) is a nice backup tool and it includes `clogin`, an Expect script to access Cisco devices (at least IOS based and ASA firewalls). An usage sample: `clogin -c "sh version" 10.1.2.3 > result.txt`.

Comment: I suspect you have been downvoted as your question does not really meet stack overflow guidelines. Although people have provided examples, please post an example script you are trying to execute and you may get a better response.

Answer (score 2):

This is a small code written in python which does the work for you. Python is by default installed in your CentOS. Just save the code in file name it as .py and run it with "python .py". Let me know if this helps.

```
import pexpect


try:

hostname= 'yourhostname/ip of firewall'
username= 'your username'
commandTorun = 'Enter your command here'
password= 'your password'
enable= 'your enable password'

ssh = 'ssh ' + username + '@' +hostname

s=pexpect.spawn(ssh)

s.expect('word')
s.sendline(password)
s.expect('>');
s.sendline('en')
s.expect('word')
s.sendline(enable)
s.expect('#')
s.sendline('configure terminal')
s.expect('#')
s.sendline('pager 0')
s.expect('#')
s.sendline(commandTorun)

s.expect('#')
output =  s.before
#You can save the output however you want here. I am printing it to the CLI.

s.sendline('exit')
s.expect('#')
s.sendline('exit')
s.expect(pexpect.EOF)
print output

except Exception, e:
print "The Script failed to login"
print str(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CentOS, but I have done this on Windows using Plink - a command line version of PuTTY.  [http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html) (Edit: just checked and it appears plink exists as a .rpm file and is available on the repositories.  The link provided also has source code if manual compile is your thing.)

The option -m allows you to specify a command script, -ssh forces ssh protocol, -l is the remote user and -pw is the remote password.

Here is the command:

```
plink.exe -ssh -l user -pw pass -m "path_to_script/script.txt" ip_of_asa > outputfile.txt
```

In the script.txt file you simply a list of commands including the enable command and hardcoded password:

```
en
enable_password
show ver
 
 
exit
```

Note, there are spaces in there to get the full "show ver" if multiple pages.  The output uses the ">" to redirect output to file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I am trying to do that with expect, i see it is logging in and creating the logfile output.txt too, but the issue is it is empty. Can anybody help me out with what's wrong with belo code??

#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#! /bin/bash

set timeout 60
log_user 1
set host *********
set password **********
set enablepassword ********* 
set user *******
set logfile output.txt
spawn ssh $user@$host
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$password\r"
log_user 1
expect "*>"
send "en\r"
expect "*assword: "
send -- "$enablepassword\r"
expect "*#"
log_file $logfile
send -- "show clock\r"
#log_file
send -- "exit\r"

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set remote_server [lrange $argv 0 0]
set timeout 10
spawn ssh -M username@$remote_server
while 1 {
  expect {
    "no)?"      {send "yes\r"}
    "denied" {
                log_file /var/log/expect_msg.log
                send_log "Can't login to $remote_server. Check username and password\n";
                exit 1
             }
    "telnet:" {
                log_file /var/log/expect_msg.log
                send_log "Can't connect to $remote_server via SSH or Telnet. Something went definitely wrong\n";
                exit 2
              }
    "failed" {
                log_file /var/log/expect_msg.log
                send_log "Host $remote_server exists. Check ssh_hosts file\n";
                exit 3
             }
    timeout {
                log_file /var/log/expect_msg.log
                send_log "Timeout problem. Host $remote_server doesn't respond\n";
                exit 4
            }
    "refused" {
                log_file /var/log/expect_msg.log
                send_log "Host $remote_server refused to SSH. That is insecure.\n"
                log_file
                spawn telnet $remote_server
              }
    "sername:" {send "username\r"}
    "assword:" {send "password\r"}
    ">"        {enable}
    "#"        {break}
  }
}
send "terminal length 0\r"
expect "#"
send "show running-config\r"
log_file /opt/config-poller/tmp/poller.trash/$remote_server
expect "#"
send "exit\n"; exit 0
```

Comment: somehow log_file logfilname is creating the log file but this is not storing the output of the command like "show running-config" or "show version"...

Comment: my mistake, was missing last expect "#" before exit... it is working now..thanks a lot for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing your router through your local machine, then you can create an expect script and configure tftp in your local machine.
The script would be like.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect-f
spawn telnet Router_IP
expect "word"
sent "password"
expect "word"
sent "copy running-config tftp://$tftp/$config\n\n" #edit this line wrt system's tftp configurations.
expect "word"
send "\n"
```